# Why is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1} \right)^{2n+4} = \frac{1}{e^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28%28n-1%29/%28n%2b1%29%29%5E%282n%2b4%29), the limit of

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1} \right)^{2n+4} = \frac{1}{e^4}$$

and I wonder how this result is obtained.

My approach would be to divide both nominator and denominator by $n$, yielding

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{2n+4} $$

As $ \frac{1}{n} \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$, what remains is

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1-0}{1 + 0} \right)^{2n+4} = 1 $$

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\dfrac{1}{n}+1)^{n}=e$ is a [Classic Limit](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/LimitDefinitionOfE10.htm) definition of e.

Comment: The wrongness in your approach is in assuming that you can freely replace $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ by 0 (exactly zero). Loosely speaking: $ 1/n $ becomes "nearly" zero, so $ 1-1/n $ becomes "nearly" one, yet that "very small" difference *may* be relevant after "infinitely" many multiplications. A reference case (*the* reference case) being the limit shown by Inceptio in another comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already know that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac x{f(n)}\right)^{f(n)}=e^x\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R$$

and for any function $\,f\,$ s.t. $\,f(n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ , then

$$\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+4}=\left[\left(1-\frac2{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right]^2\left(1-\frac2{n+1}\right)^2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}(e^{-2})^2\cdot1^2=e^{-4}$$

Comment: Alright, that makes sens! However, what's wrong with my approach then? Do the best of my knowledge, I made only valid operations, yet the result is different.

Comment: You tried to apply arithmetic of limits *selectively and thus wrongly*, i.e.: you made $\,n\to \infty\,$ within the parentheses (and thus you get in there, correctly, $\;1\;$) , yet you kept the exponent, which is also a function of $\,n\,$, constant at the same time! You can't do that...:)

Answer (score 5):

The definition of $e$ is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

There are many ways in which this may be shown.  One is to use logarithms: let $L$ be the limit; then

$$\log{L} =\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log{\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \frac{1}{n} = 1$$

so that $L = e$.  Further, you can show similarly that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

Your limit is then

$$\left ( \frac{1/e}{e}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{e^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1} \right)^{2n+4} $$

$$ =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-2)}{n+1} \right)^{\frac{n+1}{-2}}\right)^{\frac{-2(2n+1)}{n+1}}$$

$$ = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{(-2)}{n+1} \right)^{\frac{n+1}{-2}}\right)^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{-4-\frac2n}{1+\frac1n}\right)}$$

$$=(e)^{-4}\text{ as } n \to \infty, \frac{n+1}{-2}\to-\infty\text{ and } \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e$$