# How to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{4+x}{1+x}\right)^{4+2x}$ (without l'Hospital maybe?)

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How to solve
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{4+x}{1+x}\right)^{4+2x}?$$

Well, it looks similar to:

$$e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + n^{-1}\right)^n,$$

but I can't get it solved. Sure, I could use l'Hospital twice (as some calculators suggest). But is that the only way? Isn't there a nice solution that I am too dumb to find?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427410/42969

Comment: Try substituting $y=\frac{x+1}3.$ Then $$\frac{x+4}{x+1}=1+\frac1y.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews then I get

$$\left( 1 + \frac{3}{1+x}\right)^{(2+x)^2}=\left(1+\frac{6}{2+2x}\right)^{(2+x)^2}$$

And then I am stuck.

Comment: @Korrola not sure what you’ve done there, but $(2+x)^2$ in the exponent is wrong. Maybe you mean $(u^v)^w$ where you’ve written $u^{v^w},$ which is normally interpreted  as $u^{(v^w)}.$ Anyway, you didn’t substitute $y=\frac{x+1}3,$ or $x=3y-1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $y=\frac{x+1}{3},$ or $x=3y-1,$ you get the equal limit:

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^{2+6y}\tag1$$

Use that $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^2=1$$ and $$\lim_{y\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e$$ to compute $(1).$

Comment: Reult is $e^6$.

Answer (score 0):

We have :
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)^{4 + 2x} & = & (4 + 2x) \ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right) \\[3mm]
& = & (4 + 2x) \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)}{\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} - 1} \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} - 1\right) \\[3mm]
& = & (4 + 2x) \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)}{\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} - 1} \dfrac{3}{1 + x} \\[3mm]
& = & \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)}{\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} - 1} \dfrac{12 + 6 x}{1 + x} \\[3mm]
& \underset{x \to +\infty}{\to} & 1 \times 6 = 6 
\end{array}$$
Notice that :
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)}{\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} - 1} = 1$$
coz :
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x} = 1$$
and we know that :
$$\lim_{t \to 1} \dfrac{\ln t}{t - 1} = 1$$
We deduce that :
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\dfrac{4 + x}{1 + x}\right)^{4 + 2x} = e^6$$

Comment: thanks, a really nice solution <3

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{4+x}{1+x}\right)^{4+2x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{4+x}{1+x}\right)^{2}\left(\left(1+\frac{3}{1+x}\right)^{\frac{1+x}3}\right)^6=e^6$$

Comment: Thank you. But I do not get how you go from 4+2x to ((1+x)/3)^6

Comment: It's $4+2x=2+(2+2x)=2+\frac{(1+x)}3 6$

Comment: Thanks <3 ... now I do get it